# How to securely insert and user user info in databases when using Google sign-in Api

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, authentication, google-signin

I am integrating Google's login Apis on a website, and I need to place the user's details in our databases to use it the next time they login.

Googles developer documents clearly out lines that developers should never store user IDs in a database, instead you should use Token IDs generated by google to auth the legitimacy of the user.

I completely agree with this, but a token's live cycle is only a short period of time. If we insert the token in our databases, the next time the user logs in, they token will be different to that in our database. So how do we auth users via token id with google sign in?

I've read all of googles developer docs https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth and theres nothing specifically explaining this, other than their process of authentication.

Could someone please help who may have had experience in this ?

Thanks alot

This is googles warning

> Warning: Do not accept plain user IDs, such as those you can get with
>   the GoogleSignInAccount.getId() method, on your backend server. A
>   modified client application can send arbitrary user IDs to your server
>   to impersonate users, so you must instead use verifiable ID tokens to
>   securely get the user IDs of signed-in users on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Googles developer documents clearly out lines that developers should never store user IDs in a database

No, they don’t.

They are telling you that your server should not trust user ids send to it directly by the client - because anyone could easily fake those.

Instead, you are supposed to send the token, that you acquired on the client side, to the server (those tokens can’t be “guessed”, therefor you can not simply fake them) - and then you make a *server-side* API call using that token, to get the user id.

Comment: thanks for your details response. These token are always changing, so if I store one token in a server today, how can I match it with anything tomorrow?

Comment: Or are the tokens meant to be stripped into segments, and only the user ID segment is stored in the database / server?

Comment: Yes, you store the user id in your database to uniquely identify the user. You just don’t trust any user ids the client would send you, but use the token server-side to request the id from the API. Tokens usually have limited validity, so you get a new one from time to time. But that has no influence on the user id, that stays the same.

Comment: Wow that is incredible and very well thought of Thanks very much. One more question good sir, if I have an existing login system that is independent of google's login Api, what happens if the user ids generated from the token are the same as an existing id found in the database created by a existing client-native login system (how do i put it in the database, if its the same user ID already in my database created from my own login system.  THANKS

Comment: You should rather not mix those IDs, that going to lead to trouble sooner or later. Store these external ids in a different column - create one for each external login provider you want to work with. Create a new user id for your own system, too, when someone signs up via Facebook. Use that "internal" user id everywhere in your system to identify the user, and use the "external" id only at login to make the connection between it and your internal user id.

Comment: Wow again, very clever thanks. Can I kindly ask if you have been reading any materials or books that teach these methods of problem solving? thanks again

Comment: Not really, no :) Facebook has some articles on general login security issues, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security And the rest is what I picked up from reading questions, discussing with other devs, etc.